# Add black border to image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have some picture  A 
and a size  `MaxH*MaxW` (as example 800*600)
the picture size is smaller,
i want to add black borders that in after the code the picture size will be 800*600

i tried something like that :

```
function [ output_args ] = t( A)
im=imread(A);
global MaxH;
global MaxW;
global Max;

[rowsA colsA numberOfColorChannelsA] = size(im); 
% Get size of existing image B. 
% See if lateral sizes match. 
if MaxH ~= rowsA || MaxW ~= colsB 
% Size of B does not match A, so resize B to match A's size. 
% imresize(A, [MaxH MaxW Max]); 
d=padarray(A,[(MaxW-size(im,1))/2 (MaxH-size(im,2))/2]);
imwrite(d,A);
end


end
```

---

```
                   **edit**

function [ output_args ] = Resize( A )
%TT Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
im=imread(A);
global MaxH;
global MaxW;
global Max;

[H W N] = size(im);

    y=floor((MaxH-H)/2);
    x=floor((MaxW-W)/2);

    d=padarray(im,[y x]);

d= imresize(d,[MaxH MaxW]);
imwrite(d,A);


end
```

tnx to all

Comment: Do you want to resize or add black border? Two different things.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this function `t`?

Comment: @Divakar i want to add black border

Comment: Replace `A` with `im` in the padarray line, i.e.  - `d=padarray(im,[(MaxW-size(im,1))/2 (MaxH-size(im,2))/2]);` The way you have written your function, remember `A` is the filename and `im` is the image data. Don't confuse it! Also, your code would over-write to the input file if present in the current directory unless of course you are using the full path, so are you sure you want that!?

Comment: @Divakar now i have the most strength error .. he make to me the resize all the images include the first that , the error is "Error using padarray
Expected input number 2, PADSIZE, to be integer-valued.

Error in padarray>ParseInputs (line 145)
validateattributes(padSize, {'double'}, {'real' 'vector' 'nonnan' 'nonnegative' ...

Error in padarray (line 65)
[a, method, padSize, padVal, direction] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});

Error in t (line 12)
d=padarray(im,[(MaxW-size(im,1))/2 (MaxH-size(im,2))/2]);"

the name of this picture is '001.jpg'

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to add black border without actually resizing the image, here's an implementation using **[`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/padarray.html)** from Image Processing Toolbox -

```
padarray(im,[(800-size(im,1))/2 (600-size(im,2))/2])
```

, where `im` is your input image data.

---

Edit: So this a correction to your code in the question and there are some not-so-preferred practices used in it which I am still keeping so that it gets working at least on your end -

```
function [ output_args ] = func100( A)
im=imread(A);
global MaxH;
global MaxW;
global Max;

[rowsA colsA numberOfColorChannelsA] = size(im);
% Get size of existing image B.
% See if lateral sizes match.
if MaxH > rowsA  & MaxW > colsA
    % Size of B does not match A, so resize B to match A's size.
    % imresize(A, [MaxH MaxW Max]);
    d=padarray(im,[(MaxW-size(im,1))/2 (MaxH-size(im,2))/2]);
else
    d = imresize(im,[MaxW MaxH]);
end
imwrite(d,A);

output_args = true;
```

end

Comment: @Divkar it write to me a mistake **Error using padarray>ParseInputs (line 188)
Function padarray expected A (argument 1) to be numeric or logical for constant padding.

Error in padarray (line 65)
[a, method, padSize, padVal, direction] = ParseInputs(varargin{:});

Error in t (line 13)
NewImage=padarray(A,[(MaxW-size(im,1))/2 (MaxH-size(im,2))/2]);
 **

Comment: it always write to me the same error  **   Error using padarray
Expected input number 2, PADSIZE, to be nonnegative.

Error in padarray>ParseInputs (line 145)
validateattributes(padSize, {'double'}, {'real' 'vector'
'nonnan' 'nonnegative' ...
Error in padarray (line 65)
[a, method, padSize, padVal, direction] =
ParseInputs(varargin{:});

Error in tt (line 16)
    d=padarray(im,[y x]);
Error in video (line 34)
    tt(file_name1);
Error in FramesRotate (line 35)
video();

Error in rotationGUI>ok_Callback (line 65)
FramesRotate();
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
>>        **

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image `A`, you can create a zeros matrix `NewImage` on the desired size and then insert (center) the image in there.
It would look somethign like this:

```
ImSize=size(A);
NewImage=zeros(MaxH,MaxW); %or was it zeros(MaxW,MaxH)?
NewImage(round((MaxH-ImSize(1))/2):round(MaxH-(MaxH-ImSize(1))/2)-1,...
         (round(MaxW-ImSize(2))/2):round(MaxW-(MaxW-ImSize(2))/2)-1)=A;
```

Comment: dear friend... this code write to me _Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index 
_   and the picture that he make to me its a black borders and in the middle some white pixels

Comment: When "zeroing" your NewImage, you likely want to declare it as uint8 or uint16. That should solve this issue. Eg: zeros(MaxH,MaxW,'uint8')

Comment: @Benoit_11 in uint8 -its make the same thing .. in uint16 i get a error **Error using writejpg>set_jpeg_props (line 184)
UINT16 image data requires bitdepth specifically set to either 12 or 16.

Error in writejpg (line 50)
props = set_jpeg_props(data,varargin{:});

Error in imwrite (line 473)
        feval(fmt_s.write, data, map, filename, paramPairs{:});

Error in t (line 20)
imwrite(NewImage,A);**

Comment: mhh ok. Can you update your answer and show the output of 'imfinfo(A)'? That would help better solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: you divided the difference of of sizes by two, if one of the sizes is an odd number the result of that operation will be a float (.5). To solve this just round or floor the expresions... (see edit) also Benoit_11's comment